# Adding parenthasis in HTML ordered list

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview, html-lists

I am working on an iPhone application in which I am loading HTML content in UIWebView.
I want to create a list like this format:

(1) item1

(2) item2

(3) item3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for your kind answers....
I got the solution by using a different way.
Rather than customizing ordered list I used table to show the data in which my numbered list with parenthesis is in 1st column and the related text is in another column.
It looks like a nice ordered list.

Answer (score 5):

```
ol {list-style-type: none;}
li:before {content: "(" counter(section, lower-alpha) ") ";}
li { counter-increment: section;}
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chumillas/NbNvy/

Comment: @yakatz:I think no.I tried above answer and hence I think it should be in html tag format.

Comment: @Chumillas:The site given doesn't work,or I couldn't use it properly.Can you please guide?

Comment: @Chumillas:It seems to be working but showing three errors in CSS code .I don't know CSS :(

Comment: 1.line 1:Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.   2.line 1:missing semicolon  3.line 1:missing semicolon

Comment: Its working? Sorry but i cant solve that :s. By the way, put your CSS code into `<style type="text/css"> </style>`

Comment: @Yogi, learning CSS is not so hard and is necessary if you plan on working with modern web pages. I am not sure how you plan to write something in HTML without using CSS; HTML is meant for describing the logical structure of a page - CSS for formatting. You need to use the  "Semantic Web". You can look at the semantic web using a screen reader meant for blind people. If you used markup to format your page, making it unreadable, then you have a problem. (I'm not saying this applies directly to your iOS project, but it is something general to keep in mind.)  [/rant]

Comment: @yakatz:Absolutely right.It's always good to have knowledge of other technologies which can be use in support to your main programming language.But at the this time it was a case of an urgent delivery and I was not having that much time to learn the language.Also iPhone doesn't support CSS format.Anyway,your advice is very correct and I will always try to learn the languages which can support my main language programming:)

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to put the numbers into the item contents and to use unordered list without bullets.

`<ul style="list-style-type: none">` 
`<li>1)item one</li>`
 `<li>2)item two</li>`
 `</ul>`

Comment: Thanks,but if I try this the formatting doesn't look correct i.e.the text comes bellow numbers

Answer (score 0):

That format is not included in standard HTML/CSS.
[This site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp) lists the options and [this site](http://www.somacon.com/p357.php) allows you to try out how they look without writing any code.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't contain the style which I want.I want to know how can I customize the style as per my requirements

Comment: @Yogi, the point of my answer is that you can't get the format you want from traditional HTML and CSS unless you use CSS3 (which will only work if CSS3 is supported in the UIWebView.)